# Centering annotation on a log scale with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following, self-explanatory situation; please see the figure and working example pasted below.

I wonder how to center text in the middle of the dimension line.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Dimension line
def annotation_line(ax, xmin, xmax, y, text, ytext=0, linecolor='black', linewidth=1, fontsize=12):
    ax.annotate('', xy=(xmin, y), xytext=(xmax, y), xycoords='data', textcoords='data', arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '|-|', 'color':linecolor, 'linewidth':linewidth})
    ax.annotate('', xy=(xmin, y), xytext=(xmax, y), xycoords='data', textcoords='data', arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '<->', 'color':linecolor, 'linewidth':linewidth})
    xcenter = xmin + (xmax - xmin) / 2
    if ytext==0:
        ytext = y + ( ax.get_ylim()[1] - ax.get_ylim()[0] ) / 20
    ax.annotate(text, xy=(xcenter, ytext), ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=fontsize)

# Toy data
N = 8
y = np.zeros(N)
x1 = np.linspace(1, 1000, N, endpoint=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.plot(x1, y, 'o')
annotation_line(ax=ax, text='TEXT 1', xmin=1, xmax=100, y=0.01, ytext=0, linewidth=1, linecolor='gray', fontsize=12)
ax.set_xscale('log')
```

[image]

Comment: You could calculate the center in logspace and then take the exponent: `xcenter = 10**((np.log10(xmin) + np.log10(xmax) ) / 2)`. Note that this is equivallent to `xcenter = (xmin * xmax) ** .5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to do as @JohanC suggests and calculate the midpoint in log coordinates.

An other solution is to use the coordinates of the arrow to find it's midpoint. There are drawbacks to that method however. First, you need to explicitly draw the figure at an intermediate step, since the coordinates will only be valid at the time of drawing, and second, you need to set the log-scale before drawing the annotation. On the other hand, the code works regardless of the scaling of the axes

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Dimension line
def annotation_line(ax, xmin, xmax, y, text, ytext=0, linecolor='black', linewidth=1, fontsize=12):
    an = ax.annotate('', xy=(xmin, y), xytext=(xmax, y), xycoords='data', textcoords='data', arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '|-|', 'color':linecolor, 'linewidth':linewidth})
    ax.annotate('', xy=(xmin, y), xytext=(xmax, y), xycoords='data', textcoords='data', arrowprops={'arrowstyle': '<->', 'color':linecolor, 'linewidth':linewidth})
    ax.figure.canvas.draw() # draw to get actual coordinates
    p = an.arrow_patch.get_path().transformed(ax.transAxes.inverted())
    xmin, xmax = np.min(p.vertices[:,0]),np.max(p.vertices[:,0])
    xcenter = xmin+(xmax-xmin)/2
    if ytext==0:
        ytext = y + ( ax.get_ylim()[1] - ax.get_ylim()[0] ) / 20
    ax.annotate(text, xy=(xcenter, ytext), xycoords=('axes fraction','data'), ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=fontsize)
    return an

# Toy data
N = 8
y = np.zeros(N)
x1 = np.linspace(1, 1000, N, endpoint=True)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.plot(x1, y, 'o')
ax.set_xscale('log') # must do before the call to annotation_line
an = annotation_line(ax=ax, text='TEXT 1', xmin=1, xmax=100, y=0.01, ytext=0, linewidth=1, linecolor='gray', fontsize=12)
```